# Are there available scripts for TexWorks making a list of all labels used in a latex document?

Tags: texworks

Having used emacs for editing latex documents, I am used to a tool that lists all labels used in a master file and its input files. This tool is extremely usefull when referring to tables and figures and sections other places in the document. Is there some script (Pyton or QT) available that makes this functionaly for TexWork users?

Comment: See: http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=18

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a feature request of TeX Works. I think such questions should be asked at [TeXWorks development page](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/list)

At the linked page you will find [Issue 18: Completion in references, citations](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=18).

The issue is well answered by Henrik Skov Midtiby who provided a script with your request functionality. The script is available at GitHub:

[GitHub henrikmidtiby/TeXworks-scripts](https://github.com/henrikmidtiby/TeXworks-scripts/tree/master/autocomplete)

> This script adds autocompletion functionality to TeXworks.
>   Autocompletion is based on where the cursor is placed

Comment: Well, your probably right with respect to asking this question in another place, but autocompletion is not primarily what I need, but a list of all labels that exist in all files used together with a master file.

Comment: Sorry. Than you can adapt this one: http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=261#c22

Comment: sorry again, the script you refer to produces new lables. My need is a list of already used lables. And in addition, I have no clue as to how to change these .js files if I found one I could use  :)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem here using Windows 10 and I could not find a proper "script" for TexWorks. But after 8 years of this question, I found this (without scripts):

TexWorks have an option that show you the name of the parts, chapters, section, subsections, etc of the *current* documment. This structural information can be display clicking **Window**, **Show** and **Tags**. This menu does not show you the label marks, but it *does* in a certain way if you edit one of the text documment in the configuration files. Let me explain it:

- On TexWorks, go to the **Help** menu, **Setting and Resources** and
  click at the **Resources** directory.
- In the explorer, search for the **configuration** file and click it,
  then right click on the file called ***"tag-patterns"*** and click
  properties, this is just to change the *Only Lecture* option, so
  click it and desactivate it.
- Then open it with any editor, I use Notepad for example. There is a
  part that says *"# Patterns for LaTeX sectioning commands:"*, select
  and copy the first line and paste it at the end of that paragraph.

Now just change the number 1 for the following at the list and change the name of the command to ***"label"***, just like this:

```
# Patterns for LaTeX sectioning commands:
1   ^\s*\\part\*?\s*(?:\[[^]]*\]\s*)?\{([^}]*)\}
2   ^\s*\\chapter\*?\s*(?:\[[^]]*\]\s*)?\{([^}]*)\}
3   ^\s*\\section\*?\s*(?:\[[^]]*\]\s*)?\{([^}]*)\}
4   ^\s*\\subsection\*?\s*(?:\[[^]]*\]\s*)?\{([^}]*)\}
5   ^\s*\\subsubsection\*?\s*(?:\[[^]]*\]\s*)?\{([^}]*)\}
6   ^\s*\\label\*?\s*(?:\[[^]]*\]\s*)?\{([^}]*)\}
```

And now, when you open the **Tags** option, it should display all the structure of the documment including the label marks with the name they got it.

Sadly, it does not change the **Table of Content** option for the PDF viewer (it can be found also on **Window** and **Show** menu). Maybe it would follow the same idea, but I could not find it yet.

*Achtung!* If you do not have the `hyperref` package on the documment, you cannot see the Table of Content correctly, check [5.4 Showing the tags ,Other tools, A short manual for TEXworks](https://frcatel.fri.uniza.sk/users/beerb/latex/TeXworks/GoingfurtherOthertools.html#x31-340005.4).

*Achtung!* This work when compilating with `pdfLaTeX` , not with `ConTeXt`.

Probably this "method" could work with `\index{}`, but I do not really recommend it.

Hope someone find this useful, and if it is something wrong with this, please comment it below!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!